# How to analyse a nesting variable in ANCOVA

Tags: ancova

I am conducting an experiment with one continuous response variable, four categorical explanatory variables (breed, breed line, time of day tested, reproductive status) and one continuous explanatory variable (age). As I understand the appropriate test for this data would be an ANCOVA.

I have two levels for Breed, and breed line has two levels, but only within one level of breed. i.e. One of the two breeds I am testing has two clear breed lines but the other does not.

Essentially, my question is can I use ANCOVA with breed line nested within only one level of the Breed explanatory factor?

Thanks in advance